# Test that an Angular observable emits a value or sequence

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, rxjs, observable

I have a service that creates an observable that emits values, and it's relatively easy to test that an emitted value is as expected.

For example:

```
describe('service', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({providers: [MyService]});
    });

    it('should emit true', async(() => {
        const service = TestBed.get(MyService);
        service.values$.subscribe((value) => expect(value).toBeTruthy());
    }));
});
```

The above works to test the expected value, but it only works if the service actually emits a value. If you have the edge case where the service fails to emit a value, then the test itself actually passes and Jasmine logs the warning message "SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS should be created".

I searched Google for a while trying to figure out how to catch this case as an error and came up with this approach.

```
    it('should emit true', async(() => {
        const service = TestBed.get(MyService);
        let value;
        service.values$.subscribe((v) => value = v);
        expect(value).toBeTruthy();
    }));
```

The above works only for *synchronous* observables and feels like code smell to me. Another developer will see this and think it's a poor quality test.

So after thinking about this for a few days. I thought of using `takeUntil()` to force the observable to complete and then test the expected result then.

For example:

```
describe('service', () => {
    let finished: Subject<void>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({providers: [MyService]});
        finished = new Subject();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        finished.next();
        finished.complete();
    });

    it('should emit true', async(() => {
        const service = TestBed.get(MyService);
        let value;
        service.changes$
            .pipe(
                takeUntil(finished),
                finalize(() => expect(value).toBeTruthy())
            )
            .subscribe((v) => value = v);
    }));
});
```

In the above example the value is being stored in a local variable and then the expected result is checked when the observable completes. I force the completion by using `afterEach()` with `takeUntil()`.

**Question:**

Are there any side effects with my approach, and if so what would be the more Angular/Jasmine way of performing these kinds of tests. I am worried that you are not suppose to perform *expect* assertions during the *afterEach()* life-cycle call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems overkill to me.

Jasmine offers a callback in its tests, you could simply use it ?

```
it('should X', doneCallback => {
  myObs.subscribe(res => {
    expect(x).toBe(y);
    doneCallback();
  });
});
```

If the callback isn't called, the test fails with a timeout exception (meaning no more test will run after this failed one)

Comment: Overkill is my middle name. Thanks, I'll give this a try. Everywhere I've read says you should use the Angular *async* function. How is that different?

Comment: Well for starters, that's biased, because you're not forced to use the testbed or any angular feature in your tests. For instance, we have heavy components, and we unit test our code, but the interface is tested with E2E tests (reduces the testing time **a lot**). And Angular `async` (isn't it `fakeAsync` BTW ?) simply resovles the pending operations in your code, it doesn't do much more than that. I've never used it and never encountered a test issue where my async code was pending. So it's really opinion based, but for me `async` is useless !

Comment: *facepalm*. I just read the function signature of `it()` and it supports setting a timeout value. I was under the impression that Jasmine was purely synchronous.

Comment: Sh*t happens, at least you know have way less code to type in for your tests :)